# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 20.04 and taking long to boot up in Legion

Tags: nvidia, c++

I recently installed 20.04 on my Legion laptop
As the title suggests, the Wireless connection isn't working shows Wifi Adaptor not found in settings and taking lot of time to bootup also I have tried all kind of workarounds found an forms none worked...Please help me cant reinstall ubuntu since Im in middle of a project

Here are some relevant outputs from my system -

```
salini@salini-Lenovo-Legion-5P-15IMH05H:~/Downloads/installs$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:06f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Network controller output of lspci -v

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0074
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c2498000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

lsusb output

```
salini@salini-Lenovo-Legion-5P-15IMH05H:~/Downloads/installs$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:4533 Lenovo Lenovo Portable HDD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 048d:c100 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:c955 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8295)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:60e4 Lenovo Lenovo Legion M300 RGB Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ecb:02e2 AMTelecom JMR1140
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I would greatly appreciate anyone to help me out with fixing this as I am not sure how to solve this issue.

And after this wifi issue My system is taking longer to bootup 5-6 mints!!
[Bootup screen][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciWcx.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Intel Wireless-AC 9560/9462 is not correctly enabled on IceLake
platforms.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1835879

A release has been released..

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1
```